# App isn't supported on this device (moto 360) - DialogFlow

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

When trying to run 'my test app', the google assistant tells me that the app is not supported by the device (moto 360 and huawei watch 2). Is there a way to make watches support dialogs built in dialogflow again?

Would be awesome, if you could help me out!

Comment: What have you tried so far?